High watermark file recovery. endorsement, baking, pre-endorsements
Recovery scenario for a baking node. There seems to be a change in the format of the file for the highwater mark to protect for double baking, double prendorsement etc etc. In the past the file contain the block number and only the block number.  Now here is format: { "NetXdQprcVkpaWU":
{ "tz1...":
{ "level": 0000000, "round": 0,
"hash":
"abc...",
"signature":
"edsigt..." } } }
In the case of a catastrophic and recovery is done from a backup, it wouyld be required to adjust the high-watermark files can it include only the level and blockchain? or do we need to find the hash and signature also?

The hash and signature would also be needed based on the new format.
